# Optional identifiers in cognito hosted UI do not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-userpools

I've been using SAML identity federation on my Userpool which has a hosted SignIn page. I configured both the Azure Active Directory and cognito userpool so I can log in with an AD user. I have added multiple SAML providers similar manner and that works without an issue. The problem occurs when I use **Identifiers** attribute which is used to login to the corresponding IDP by extracting the domain name from the email. I followed [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-managing-saml-idp-console.html) documentation. This is how it looks in the AWS console.

[image]

Now when I try to login with an AD user email it gives me **Login not allowed error**. It worked well when I don't use this identifiers optional parameter.

[image]

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently "Identifiers" parameter has some connection with user-pool "General Settings -> Policies". You need to select "Allow users to sign themselves up" option for IDP identifiers to work.

[image]
Although this worked when you enable sign up option there will be a link to signup on the hosted page.

In my case, I do not want users to sign themselves up. However, this is some progress.

Comment: FWIW, users first need to be confirmed in order to be able to log in, but someone could still create a ton of accounts and DoS Cognito or just fill up the account database.